# How does “dd” determine where to start copying disk blocks?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, dd

Say we have a hard drive disk and the blocks are numbered as: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc…

I assume that this command will read the disk blocks from block 0 and in sequence (1, 2, 3, 4…) right?

```
sudo dd if=/dev/nvme2n1 of=/dev/null bs=1M
```

If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> the process and run this command again, will `dd` still read from block 0?

Comment: Your title does not match the actual question, which seems to be about the starting point rather than any "*sequence*".

Comment: @sawdust sorry for the poor English, editted a bit hope it less confusing now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It starts from 0 and increments by one until it reaches the end.

It's actually not dd that determines the sequence – the kernel does. During the copy process, dd doesn't specify which sectors to read, it only uses the generic "read X bytes from *current position*" system call and relies on the kernel to keep track of what "current position" actually is.

The position always starts at 0 whenever a program opens any block device, just like for regular files. When dd calls read(1MB), it receives 1MB of data and the position is accordingly incremented by 1MB. The position is tracked for each "open file", not per device, so when you run dd again, it will start at 0 again.

Note that these operations work in terms of bytes, not disk sectors, and the "block" in `bs=` is not really referring to a disk block; it's the amount of data that 'dd' asks to read at a time. The 'dd' block size *should* be a multiple of disk sector size for best performance, but it's not technically required to match.

(In other words, `dd` works almost exactly like `cat /dev/nvme0n1p1 > /dev/null`. The only real advantage of using 'dd' to copy disks over doing the same with 'cat' or 'cp' is that it has a progress display, if you enable it.)

You can use options like `skip=` (aka `iseek=`) to have 'dd' skip a certain number of blocks, i.e. seek to a specific position in the input file (combined with `seek=`/`oseek=` for the output), e.g. running `dd if=.. of=.. iseek=1G oseek=1G` would resume at 1GB. (When the output is a regular file, you would also need `oflag=append conv=notrunc` to have dd append to output instead of truncating.)

It would be better to use tools specifically designed for incremental copying, such as *ddrescue*.

```
ddrescue /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/null /tmp/ddrescue.status
```

Comment: Thank you it's a great anwser. Why I'm asking this is because I'm pre-warming a aws EBS volume which is restored from snapshot. The pre-warm is just run the `dd` command I pasted above, before pre-warm the io latency is ~100ms, which after that the latency will drop to <1ms.  I assume if I run `dd` twice, the begining disk blocks that has been pre-warmed in the 1st run should got a <1ms latency, but seems it's not the case..  Well thank you again

Comment: What does “pre-warmed” mean?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 When AWS EBS volume is restored from a snapshot, the volume is lazy loading the data from the snapshot, so if want to get the volume's maximum performance before using it, we need to do a pre-warm(now calling Initialization) operation, it's actually a `dd` command that reads data from the volume thus force executing the lazy loading in advance

Comment: I think you need 1GB for 1GB / 1GiB for 1GiB. 1G will be considered that many (binary unit) of blocks instead bytes. (There's also the seek_bytes / skip_bytes flags.)